# MySQL query for adding two columns with shared value

Tags: mysql, select, group

A little help is needed if you'd be so kind.

I have a MySQL table entitled **hits** which records unique and non-unique visits to pages on my site. A non-unique visit is classed as a repeated visit by the same IP address within a 24-hour time period.

For the purposes of statistics, I want to analyse visits across my website. I can do that using unique and non-unique totals but not BOTH.

Here's part of the table:

[image: MySQL Hits table]

What I want to do is add together the values in the *hitcount* column regardless of whether *isunique* is 1 or 0 and then sort the results in descending order.

So, for the *pageid* 0050, I want to get 172 (95+77).

This is what I've tried:

```
$hitcountquery = "SELECT hitcount,pageid FROM hits WHERE pageid NOT LIKE '999%' GROUP BY pageid ORDER BY hitcount DESC";
```

The reason I've got that NOT LIKE in the query is that I want to ignore admin pages from the results.

Any idea what MySQL command I would need to add the totals in the *hitcount* column for each *pageid* and then sort them in descending order? I've had limited success but the titles are repeated in the table. I need them grouped so that each *pageid* appears only once in the results.

Thanks so very much in advance. You could just save my sanity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your details I think what you really want is the sum of your column, if that's the case you can use the `SUM()` function for your `hitcount` column like this:

```
$hitcountquery = "SELECT SUM(hitcount),pageid FROM hits WHERE pageid NOT LIKE '999%' GROUP BY pageid ORDER BY hitcount DESC";
```

hops this help.

Comment: Thank you. It really was that simple, huh? Thanks to you, I have some hair left!

Comment: Happy to help, have a great time :)